# Correcting non booting Win with DISM

Tags: windows-10, bsod, dism

I have tried for a few hours now, but I cant find a solution.

Windows 10 Pro x64

During boot I get a BSOD with the stop code CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED every time, same in Safe Mode. I tried system restore but it fails while mounting the registry from the restore point (all four).

Now I am booting from a Win10Pro x64 setup usb and would like to use

`x:\>Dism /online ? /cleanup-image /restorehealth` (and give as /source the one in the usb d:\sources)

Would this work ?

`x:\>Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:d:\sources\install.esd`

Edit. I hope this will allow me to keep the apps and settings.

Comment: `/online` refers to the currently running system (ie. the Windows Setup environment). I can’t currently look it up, but you need to specify the correct installation to perform maintenance on.

Comment: tried it with /checkhealth and it is indeed the setup environment. I suppose it isnt possible to replace /online with the windows in d:\

Comment: maybe Dism /Image:x:\offline